# Chrome says Updates are disabled by Administrator

Tags: windows, google-chrome, automatic-update

How to enable auto update in Chrome? I am a user with administrator rights. How can I re-enable the auto download for Google Chrome.

[image]

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you were Using Windows Machine :

Navigate to run command by pressing windows+r

Enter "**regedit**" and press Enter

Set the value of `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Update\UpdateDefault` to the `REG_DWORD` value of "1".

For further info, you can consult this article: [Control Chrome auto updates](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/YK1-o4KoSjc)

Comment: @wruckie replaced deadlink with a valid one,kindly have a check :)

Comment: If you have any keys that look like `Update{some-guid-here}` then those need to be renamed/removed as well. Might be a new thing since this was answered, as I haven't found reference to it anywhere else on the net.